# FlowRouter query parameter parsing is wrong

Tags: meteor, flow-router

When I tried to parse this URL:

http://localhost:3000/torrent?previous=%2Ftorrent%3Fprevious%3D%252Fuser%26route%3D&route=torrent-item

I was expecting `route = 'torrent-item'` (String), but FlowRouter router value is `["", "torrent-item"]` (Array)

[image]

online - https://ts-vcompile.herokuapp.com/user#!/torrent?previous=%2Ftorrent%3Fprevious%3D%252Fuser%26route%3D&route=torrent-item

repo - https://github.com/HedCET/TorrentSearch

Answer (score 0):

There is one key **route** in queryparameter which has no value. So default value assumed is an empty string. It will always return you an array of keys with same **name**(in this case 'route').

So you will not get **route = 'torrent-item'**

previous=%2Ftorrent%3Fprevious%3D%252Fuser%26**route**%3D&route=torrent-item

Comment: that's means i can't pass 'route=' as value of another query parameter

Comment: you can do anything you want. But you should expect route[1] = 'torrent-item'. OR change to "_route=", so you will get your desired output as "route='torrent-item'"

Comment: it might be route[0] = 'torrent-item' if i place route infront of previous param

Answer (score -1):

Your URL decodes as

```
http://localhost:3000/torrent?previous=/torrent?previous=%2Fuser&route=&route=torrent-item
```

cf: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

so you have `&route=&route=torrent-item` which will return `["", "torrent-item"]` since route is there twice.

You just need to figure how to encode this URL properly to read it right.

If it's a URL you are reading from somewhere, then you need to parse the multiple arguments of the array to find what you want.